# Javascript , encodeURI failed to encode round bracket "("

Tags: javascript, uri, encoder

I have cookie value which contains round bracket " e.g: demo (1)"
When I try to encode with encodeURI , the round bracket ( is not encoded to %28 , what is the alternative to encode the special characters like round brackets

Answer (score 15):

To encode uri components to be RFC 3986 -compliant - which encodes the characters `!'()*` - you can use:

```
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```

Taken from just before Examples-section at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

For reference, see: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

Answer (score 10):

`encodeURI()` encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ #.
One can use `encodeURIComponent()` to encode the above character.

You can write custom method to encode ( to %28.

Example :

```
var uri = "my test.asp?(name";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
res.replace("(", "%28");
```

As pointed out in the comment below, `string#replace` will remove the first occurrence, one can use `string#replaceAll` i.e. `res.replaceAll("(", "%28")` or `string#replace` with global flag i.e. `res.replace(/\(/g, "%28")`  to remove all occurrences.

```js
const uri = "my test.asp?(n(a(m(e",
      res = encodeURI(uri);
console.log(res.replaceAll("(", "%28"));
```

**NOTE :**
`encodeURI()` will not encode: ~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'

`encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: ~!*()'

Comment: Even encodeURIComponent() is not encoding this character 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_encodeuricomponent

Comment: Know that .replace() will only replace the first instance of "(". To replace all instances, use a regex or .split.join, such as `res.replace(/\(/g, "%28")` or `res.split("(").join("%28")`

Answer (score 4):

Based on [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) docs by Mozilla

> `encodeURIComponent` escapes all characters except:
>
> ```
> A-Z a-z 0-9 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
> ```

So, the only characters we don't want to scape are: `A-Z a-z 0-9`.

So this function does it:

```
function encodeUriAll(value) {
  return value.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9]/g, c =>
    `%${c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase()}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`encodeURI` only encodes reserved characters so this function should not be expected to encode parentheses.

You could write your own function to encode all the characters in the string, or just create a custom list of characters you want to encode.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0x96f7ng/)

```
function superEncodeURI(url) {

  var encodedStr = '', encodeChars = ["(", ")"];
  url = encodeURI(url);

  for(var i = 0, len = url.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (encodeChars.indexOf(url[i]) >= 0) {
        var hex = parseInt(url.charCodeAt(i)).toString(16);
        encodedStr += '%' + hex;
    }
    else {
        encodedStr += url[i];
    }
  }

  return encodedStr;
}
```