# I can't remove the "()" from the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I want to make a function that removes the "()" from the url: https://salgadofilho.pr.gov.br/uploads/noticia/copel_(244).jpg

so that it continues to work, I've tried to use the function below but it returns this https%3A%2F%2Fsalgadofilho.pr.gov.br%2Fuploads%2Fnoticia%2Fcopel_(244).jpg

```js
function urlEncode(url) {
  const urlDec = encodeURIComponent(url)
  return console.log(urlDec)
}


urlEncode('https://salgadofilho.pr.gov.br/uploads/noticia/copel_(244).jpg')
```

and does not remove the "()", there is no way to remove it with JS method because the url is not found. does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Why are you trying to remove the `(` ? What do you want instead?

Comment: If i understand you question maybe you need some how to delete character out of string https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Comment: url.replace(/(\\(|\\))/g, "");

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to encode parenthesis, unless you need to be RFC3986 compliant, in which case you can use the code from [this answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64317676/17914167).

```js
function fixedEncodeURIComponent(str) {
  return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
    return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  });
}
```